# Ansible task write to local log file

Tags: linux, shell, ansible

Using Ansible I would like to be able to write the sysout of a task running a command to a local(i.e. on the managed server) log file.
For the moment I can only do this using a task like this:

```
- name: Run my command
  shell: <command> <arg1> <arg3> ... |tee -a <local log file>
```

The reason to do this is that the  takes a long time to complete(i.e. we cannot wait until it finishes to get its output) and would like to collect the output during its execution.

Is there any "Ansible" way to redirect to sysout of the command to a local log file during its execution without using the `tee` pipe?

Comment: I moved the question to ServerFault (https://serverfault.com/questions/958952/ansible-task-write-to-local-log-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% answers your question as you wont get a constantly updating file in your manager server but you could use [async commands](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html)

```
# Requires ansible 1.8+
- name: 'YUM - async task'
  yum:
    name: docker-io
    state: installed
  async: 1000
  poll: 0
  register: yum_sleeper

- name: 'YUM - check on async task'
  async_status:
    jid: "{{ yum_sleeper.ansible_job_id }}"
  register: job_result
  until: job_result.finished
  retries: 30
```

and then dump the contents of `yum_sleeper` to a file with

```
- name: save log locally
  copy:
    content: '{{ yum_sleeper.stdout }}'
    dest: file.log
  delegate_to: localhost
```